# How Pre-aggregation in group by clause are done - Teradata

Tags: database, indexing, teradata, rdbms

I am reading about the difference between Distinct and Group by. [Here](https://www.dwhpro.com/distinct-vs-group-teradata/)

In case of Distinct Clause, Rows are distributed immediately without any pre-aggregation. I got this point. I know what redistribution is and how it happens behind the scene.

In the case of GROUP BY, in a first step a preaggregation is done and only then are the unique values redistributed across the AMPs.

I am confused what really preaggregation are here? and How they are done? Any Explanation Thanks.

Comment: Are you speaking of [partion aggregation](https://www.info.teradata.com/HTMLPubs/DB_TTU_16_00/index.html#page/SQL_Reference/B035-1142-160K/hwy1472241595055.html) before a join?

Comment: What presentation are you reading? Give us a reference to it & quote the first place you are stuck in it & describe how you are stuck. Please don't ask us to write another one.

Comment: I am reading about the difference between Distinct and Group by. Here https://www.dwhpro.com/distinct-vs-group-teradata/

Comment: In case of Distinct Clause, Rows are distributed immediately without any pre-aggregation. I got this point. I know what redistribution is and how it happens behind the scene.

Comment: whereas pre-aggregation is done first in case of Group BY clause and then redistribution of unique rows. What I am not getting is how pre-aggregation is done behind the scene( what pre aggregation is? ). From conceptual point of view.

Comment: no one to answer?